# OpenCV: Highlights Adjustment Without Affecting Shadows

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I originally attempted to use the script located [here](https://gist.github.com/HViktorTsoi/8e8b0468a9fb07842669aa368382a7df) to darken the highlights of a captured 8mm film frame without affecting the shadows.

I never call the script with parameters that returned an acceptable improvement in the image. I have since attempted to try this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter) 

def gammaCorrection(src, gamma):
    invGamma = 1 / gamma
 
    table = [((i / 255) ** invGamma) * 255 for i in range(256)]
    table = np.array(table, np.uint8)
 
    return cv2.LUT(src, table)


image = cv2.imread(r'X:\temp2\Test00001-02.jpg')
resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=1280) # Resize by width OR
# resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, height=1280) # Resize by height 

cv2.imshow('Image', resize)


#gammaImg = gammaCorrection(resize, 0.3)
 
#cv2.imshow('Gamma corrected image', gammaImg)


# Convert to HSV and take V channel
V = cv2.cvtColor(resize,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[...,2]

# Threshold V channel at 100 to make alpha channel (A)
_, A = cv2.threshold(V,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Threshold V channel at 100 to make alpha channel (A)
_, A2 = cv2.threshold(V,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Stack A channel onto RGB channels
result = np.dstack((resize,A))

# Stack A channel onto RGB channels
fullchannel = np.dstack((resize,A2))
gammaImg = gammaCorrection(result, 0.3)
final_im = cv2.addWeighted(fullchannel, 1, gammaImg, 0.5, 0)


# Save result
cv2.imwrite(r'X:\temp2\original_im.png',resize)
cv2.imwrite(r'X:\temp2\final_im.png',final_im)
cv2.imwrite(r'X:\temp2\gamma_adjusted.png',gammaImg)
cv2.imwrite(r'X:\temp2\fullchannel.png',fullchannel)
```

The following images show the output of this script.

Original Image:
[image]

Gamma Adjusted Image:
[image]

Full Channel Image:
[image]

Final Image:
[image]

The final image actually makes the highlights in the image even brighter, so there is something I am doing wrong when I merge the gamma adjusted image with the full channel image.

So, any thoughts on getting just the highlights above a set threshold to darken and not affect the darker regions of the image?

Comment: Create mask for the bright areas by thresholding. Then use cv2.normalize() with the mask option to adjust the brightness as desired.

Comment: You could also just apply a power function to the image to suppress brighter pixels more than darker ones. That is for example graylevel**2 or some other power. Or just multiply the image by itself.

Comment: might require some "high dynamic range" thinking. the "highlights" look like they'd go higher but were soft-clipped (I guess photochemistry works like that). you'll need a transfer curve that expands those highlights upwards. then you can think about mapping that to something that looks okay (tone mapping). -- you'll certainly have trouble getting the "bleeding" (halo) under control... that would require some modeling of the effect and trial-and-error to compensate for/remove it.